# Breezejs giving error in query on OData

Tags: breeze

i am trying to query web api service with odata using breezejs and angular
i am getting metadata with the correct properties

```
<Property Name="IncidentID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
    <Property Name="IncidentType" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="Description" Type="Edm.String" />
```

when i am sending the query

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("Incidents").where("IncidentType", "lt", 60);
```

i am getting error which claims the the property IncidentType doesnt exists

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I'm not sure, but it's worth checking if you possibly have a  namingConvention, possibly 'camelCase', set up. If so then "IncidentType" would become "incidentType". i.e:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("Incidents").where("incidentType", "lt", 60);
```

The other possibility is that your resource name "Incidents" is incorrect.

Best way to determine this kind of issue is to look at the client side metadata more closely. Use the MetadataStore.getEntityType method for this.

```
 // assuming an entityType of "Incident" is associated with the "Incidents" resource name.
 var et = myEntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Incident");
 var dataProperties = et.dataProperties; // check the names on each of these.
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem - the camel naming was set

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @nalply this might actually be the answer, li-raz can you update more specifically which name was incorrect and provide the correct value?

Comment: @jszumski, you are right. It's a template answer from moderation tools. What I meant is: this answer is not detailed enough.

Comment: i meant the when i used in breeze the camel naming instead of IncidentType which is what i declared on i had to write incidentType